# Starting Tags of Html Text

Tags: c#, html, css

I have extracted some text from an html document. Now i need to extract the html tags of this text too. How can i do this

Example:
Input text :

```
<td><div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="left"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: arial, sans-serif; COLOR: #2995d2; FONT-SIZE: 36pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">New Jobs</font></div></td> <td valign={0}top{0} width={0}40%{0} style={0}TEXT-ALIGN: right{0}></td>
```

Extracted Text:

```
New Jobs</font></div></td> <td valign={0}top{0} width={0}40%{0} style={0}TEXT-ALIGN: right{0}></td>
```

Now i need the starting tags of this text too. How to get them ?

Comment: How have you gone about doing this so far? What does your extraction code look like? What programming language are you using? This needs much more detail.

Comment: I'm using C#. i just found the required text in the file and then extracted it until the end but i need starting tags too

Comment: You should use a HTML parser, such as [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack). However, what you should do _first_ is sit back and formulate what the exact requirements are for your project. As stated now, the question to this answer is simply, the same as the input.

Comment: Oh, and it's not real HTML, but you probably know that. Be aware though that a HTML parser may make this come out like `width="{0}40%{0}"` etc.

Comment: thanks everyone, its resolved